# What does #pragma pack () call do?

Tags: c

I was given the following structs:

```
struct s2 {
int f0;
char f1;
unsigned long long f2;
unsigned long f3;
short f4;
long f5;
};

#pragma pack (1)
struct s2_packed {
int f0;
char f1;
unsigned long long f2;
unsigned long f3;
short f4;
long f5;
};
#pragma pack ()

struct s3 {
unsigned short f0;
int f1;
unsigned int f2;
int f3;
unsigned short f4;
char f5;
};
```

I understand `s2_packed` should be packed now, but is `s3` packed? What does the call `#pragma pack ()` do?

**UPDATE**

I just examined the bytes in s3 and they are indeed packed.. Not sure whats going on here, any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here is my `makefile` I was given:

```
all: 
 gcc -m32 -g -O -Wall struct.c main.c -o struct

clang:
 clang -m32 -g -O -Wall struct.c main.c -o struct

strict:
 gcc -m32 -g -O -Wall -Werror struct.c main.c -o struct

clang-strict:
 clang -m32 -g -fsanitize=undefined -O -Wall -Werror struct.c main.c -o struct

clean:
 rm -f struct
```

Comment: What C compiler are you using. `#pragma pack` (which is a directive, not a call, BTW) is non-standard. The meaning may depend on which compiler you're using -- and should be specified in your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @KeithThompson I have added my makefile to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#pragma pack ()
```

with `gcc` and some other compilers restores the default packing of the implementation.

Documentation for `gcc` of this `#pragma` is here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: I just examined the bytes in s3 and they are indeed packed.. Not sure whats going on here, any ideas?

Comment: @Deekor What is the value of `sizeof (struct s3)` in your machine? Tested with `gcc` on x86 and x64 gives me `20`, which is NOT packed as the sum of the size of the members would be 17 (= 2 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 1).

Comment: @ouah "pack() ...  restores the default packing of the implementation" - This isn't very helpful in identifying what pack does. I came here looking for an answer to what #pragma pack() does and this answer isn't it..